# Como puedo guardar un dato en un archivo con python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tengo este codigo pero da error la consola porque no puede agregar source_code
ya chequé su tipo de dato y es un string no sé por que no puede añadirlo

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")

a = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd() + "/index.html")
print(type(source_code))

f = open(a, 'w')
try:
    f.write(source_code)
except:
    f.close()
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode 
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f510' in position 4387: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: y qué error da?

Comment: ya edité cual es el error

Comment: Añade la zona donde aparece el error